# Why do pgadmin III views show up as empty ArcSDE geodatabase tables in ArcCatalog?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgresql, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, pgadmin-3

I have an SDE geodatabase connection set up in a server with data stored in a postgres database.

I have successfully created views using pgadmin III but they show up as empty tables in ArcCatalog (10.2).

What could be causing this, and what is the solution?

Comment: Please edit the question to include the versions of PG and ArcGIS, and give an example of the SQL definitions of the table and view.  Keep in mind that ArcGIS requires a rowid in all feature classes, and that views must be registered with the 'sdelayer' utility.  If you used 'sdelayer', please provide your syntax (less password, of course).

Comment: I am not exactly sure what the definitions are that you are looking for, however I found something else that might be useful. When I try and open the database tables in Arc (also stored in pgadmin III 1.18) I get an error that says "dbms table not found"

Comment: CREATE TABLE and CREATE VIEW statements would work.  What user owns the table?  Is there a schema with the same name?

Comment: Good questions! I just looked at the users/schemas and the tables were in the wrong schema and had the wrong owner. I fixed that, now the tables are working in ArcCatalog, the views are still empty when viewed in Arc.

Comment: Which is why the CREATE TABLE and CREATE VIEW and sdelayer parameters are necessary.

Comment: Could you please explain more? I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: There's probably a half-dozen ways, but clicking on the table or view in pgAdmin-III will show the creation SQL in the SQL Pane (Ctrl-Alt-S to toggle)

Comment: Oh ok. I already have the CREATE VIEW

Comment: You need to update the question to provide the CREATE TABLE and CREATE VIEW and 'sdelayer -o register' command options in order for your problem to be resolved.

Comment: Is this in the query? Could you provide an example of the syntax?

Comment: I got it. The issue was actually that I was using field name aliases